# REST Easy configuration problem(Servlet container 4.0 and JAX-RS 2.1)

Tags: java, rest, maven, resteasy

I have been trying to build a basic rest service using Rest easy from more than 10 hours and I am unable to find out what I have been doing wrong. Please look into my code below and let me know. Thank you.

**Resource Class**

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/test")
@Produces("application/xml")
public class Test {

    @GET
    public Response testing() {
        return Response.status(200).build();
    }
}
```

**Resource Application class**

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class TestApplication extends Application{

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<Class<?>> empty = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return empty; 
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>ims</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>InventoryMaintenanceSystem</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <description>This project deals with providing resources needed for Inventory Maintenance System</description>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <name>jboss repo</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>ims</finalName>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.1.jre8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I run it, all it shows me is not found when given the URL http://localhost:port/artifact-id/application-level-path/class-level-path/method-level-path/parameters.
Kindly guide me to a solution, thank you!

Comment: The URL I tried here is http://localhost:portNumber/ims/rest/test

Comment: Thanks to whoever was trying to help me, I managed to find a solution myself. The problem got resolved when I added maven dependencies to the web deployment assembly.